# Is the sleeping beauty paradox really one?

Tags: paradox

*See [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_Beauty_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_Beauty_problem) for the statement of this problem.*

This seems to me to be a simple weighted average problem. Because the total number of days awake varies between 1 (Monday if heads) or 2 (Monday and Tuesday if tails on Monday). The frequency of occurrence (or the weight) that tossed coin on Monday is 1 (=100% for every Monday) and on Tuesday is ½ (=50% for one Tuesday over two in average). Then:

[image: equations_1]

Then, the sleeping beauty’s answer is **50%** and is not a paradox at all, isn’t it? The classic misunderstanding is to consider that there are three events (or steps) and think that the answer is one-third. But there are not three steps. This is relative to frequencies. Another view is that obviously:

[image: equations_2]

Finally, and until proven otherwise, each time you wake up, with a balanced coin, there is always as much chance of getting heads as tails, isn’t there? So, the answer is obviously 50%. Is there really still confusion about this?

Comment: Relevant post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41208/the-sleeping-beauty-paradox

Comment: Intelligent people disagree so either it is  badly worded or it is an interesting question